# libvlc 4.0.0-eap9 random crash on android

Tags: java, android, crash, sample, libvlc

Please find here the details about project.

Android- Java
Gradle 7.2.2
Gradle version 8.1
minSdk 22
targetSdk 32

Debug
minifyEnabled false

`dependencies { implementation 'org.videolan.android:libvlc-all:4.0.0-eap9' }`

RTSP stream 0 video info - Codec H264-Mpeg-4 AVC
Resolution 1920 X 1080
Frame rate 12.5

From the sample code surface view has been used -

```
  <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/surfaceLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
  </SurfaceView>
```

Java code -

private SurfaceView surfaceLayout;
surfaceLayout = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceLayout);

```
  final ArrayList<String> args = new ArrayList<>();
                    args.add("-vvv");
                    MainActivity.libVlc = new LibVLC(callingAct, args);
                    MainActivity.mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(MainActivity.libVlc);
                    MainActivity.mediaPlayer.detachViews();
                    final IVLCVout vlcVout = MainActivity.mediaPlayer.getVLCVout();
                    vlcVout.setVideoView(surfaceLayout);
                    vlcVout.attachViews();
                    // MainActivity.mediaPlayer.attachViews(videoLayout, null, false, false);
                    Media media;
  media = new Media(MainActivity.libVlc, Uri.parse(cam2url));
 media.setHWDecoderEnabled(false, false);

                    media.addOption("--network-caching=20000");
                    media.addOption("--live-caching=20000");
                    media.addOption("--sout-mux-caching=20000");
                    media.addOption(":clock-jitter=0");
                    media.addOption(":clock-synchro=0");

                    // media.addOption(":fullscreen");
                    media.addOption(":no-audio");
       MainActivity.mediaPlayer.setAspectRatio("16:9");
 MainActivity.mediaPlayer.setScale(1f);
  MainActivity.mediaPlayer.setMedia(media);
                    media.release();
                    MainActivity.mediaPlayer.play();
```

Problem -
This code runs perfectly fine. but randomly crashes without leaving any clue.

logcat shows below errors.

Failed to find layer (SurfaceView - com

Failed to find layer (Background for - SurfaceView -

Failed to find layer

libvlc gl: gl_gpu_finish: OpenGL error: GL_INVALID_ENUM

```
Encountered errors while detecting GPU capabilities GPU does not seem to support lossless texture readback, restricting  readback capabilities! This is a GLES/driver limitation,

libvlc decoder: Could not find an AWINDOW decoder device

libvlc decoder: video context creation failed

libvlc decoder: buffer deadlock prevented
```

I am expecting constant video view, without any crash. This has been deployed on android firestick.
there is no reason for random crashing. Memory usage and CPU usage is also low, and some times it throws lot of errors.

Any help in configuring the libvlc would be helpful.

Regards

Comment: report it on gitlab, with the hash commit used of the libvlc version

Comment: Having this exact same issue on android as well, tho I am using unity.
I can hear the video file play without problems, but no video output(rendering to texture produces no output), same error you have and all. :/